# Averaging Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: curve-fitting

I have several (x,y) datasets which form various CDF curves. These are generated by cross-validating models built with different parameters. For example:

```
Aa = [0, 0.1
1, 0.2,
2, 0.3,
...
xn, yn]

Ab = [0, 0.1
    1, 0.2,
    2, 0.3,
    ...
    xn, yn]
```

Where `Aa` and `Ab` refer to curves generated by cross-validating a model built on parameter combination `Pa`.

And I then have:

```
Ba = [0, 0.1
1, 0.2,
2, 0.3,
...
xn, yn]

Bb = [0, 0.1
    1, 0.2,
    2, 0.3,
    ...
    xn, yn]
```

Where `Ba` and `Bb` refer to curves generated by cross-validating a model built on parameter combination `Pb`.

My first step would be to average `Aa` and `Ab`to produce an average curve `A` and `Ba` and `Bb`an average curve `B`. I thought about simply averaging y-values, but I can't guarantee that all curves would share the same x-values so that wouldn't work.

Next, I need to decide whether `A` and `B` are significanlty different.

I thought about two possible strategies:

a) Use Matlab's polyfit function to fit the datasets to a polynomial function, and use a t-test to compare polynomial coefficients.

b) Use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to compare x/y values for each point.

Any advice?

Comment: For determining difference between curves the KS test should work fine, although [plotting the CDF's](http://blog.thegrandlocus.com/2014/09/mis-using-the-ks-test-for-p-hacking) is seemingly a must in addition to just the test. Fitting polynomial functions sounds inefficient and potentially misleading - CDF is monotonic, and can have steps, etc.